# MS Access - VBA - create new Excel workbook

Tags: vba, ms-access

i use the following VBA-function to read an Excel-file and "create" a new workbook to save this as CSV-file.
This works fine when i run this function for the first time. 
Will i run this again it will not open a new workbook (no Errors returned) and i have to close MS Access and then i call this function again.

Has somebody an idea what i'm doing wrong?

```
   public function fctImportExcel ()  

      Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
      Dim wbExcel As Excel.Workbook
      Dim wbCSV As Excel.Workbook
      Dim wsExcel As Excel.Worksheet
      Dim wsCSV As Excel.Worksheet

      Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
      Set wbExcel = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("filepath")
      Set wsExcel = wbExcel.Sheets("sheet1")
      objExcel.Visible = True

      objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

      wsExcel.Range(wsExcel.Cells(i, 7), wsExcel.Cells(i, 25).End(xlDown)).Copy

      Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Add
      Set wsCSV = wbCSV.Sheets("sheet")

      wsCSV.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
      objExcel.CutCopyMode = False

      wbCSV.SaveAs FileName:="workbook.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

      wbCSV.Close acSaveNo
      Set wsCSV = Nothing
      Set wbCSV = Nothing

      objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True

      wbExcel.Close acSaveNo
      objExcel.CutCopyMode = False
      objExcel.Quit

      Set wsExcel = Nothing
      Set wbExcel = Nothing
      Set objExcel = Nothing

     End Function
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to open a workbook named `"filepath"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always must be extremely specific with Excel objects. So try:

```
Set wbCSV = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
```

and careful to close in reverse order:

```
  wbCSV.Close acSaveNo
  Set wsCSV = Nothing
  Set wbCSV = Nothing

  wbExcel.Close acSaveNo
  Set wsExcel = Nothing
  Set wbExcel = Nothing

  objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
  objExcel.CutCopyMode = False
  objExcel.Quit

  Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: Note that the large close section can be simplified to `wbCSV.Close acSaveNo` `wbExcel.Close acSaveNo` `objExcel.Quit`, the objects will get removed once out of scope. Unsetting in reverse order is good practice, but should not matter, since the Excel Application object and the workbooks have references to eachother, and since it's no problem to have a reference to a closed workbook/application as long as you don't use it. Only the first part of the answer is truly required.

Comment: Eagle eye badge. :) I had read through the code, but didn't spot the one unqualified call.

Comment: @ErikA: Well, "should" as you wrote, and that may be the case. However, experience has learned me not to cut any corner in this just to save a few trivial code lines.